# How can apache be allowed to send email?

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, sendmail

I have a CentOS 6.2 virtual machine running Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3 that I'm trying to send email from via PHP's mail() function. I can send email from the CLI without problems but when PHP tries it fails. In the sendmail log is the following:

```
Oct  9 11:42:03 localhost sendmail[3080]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(apache): can not chdir(/var/spool/clientmqueue/): Permission denied
```

It seems like Apache doesn't have permission to do this but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've found a lot discussion about this but nothing specific enough to what I'm doing that I could use. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: How are you trying to send this email? Apache should never need to chdir into the mail spool directories - it should just speak to the local mail MTA.

Comment: Check out this solution: http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=32273

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to check if permission are correct. Here is the permission below in my system

`# ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail` 
`-r-xr-sr-x root smmsp /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail`

`# ls -l /var/spool/clientmqueue` 
`drwxrwx--- smmsp smmsp /var/spool/clientmqueue`

If your permissions or ownership is wrong then change it using chown and chmod.

If the above is right then disable selinux or if you want selinux enabled use chcon to set the correct selinux context.

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html

For disabling selinux  temporarily use `#setenforce 0`

Comment: Don't disable SELinux  :(   There's a boolean `httpd_can_sendmail` to allow the web-server to send mail which should work in this case.  Set this with `setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1`, and include the `-P` option to make it persistent across reboots.

Answer (score 31):

Selinux may cause the issue, to verify run:

```
getsebool -a | grep mail
```

If it displays as bellow it is selinux:

```
allow_postfix_local_write_mail_spool --> off
```

You may disabled it, but if you want to keep it (and you should as it provides an extra layer of security) you should do something else:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```

This will allow the httpd to send emails, as when you use php mail().

Comment: -P option make it permanent, so after reboot it will be on again :)

Comment: i only used "setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on" and solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Hate to necro this, but none of the solutions here worked for me. I know very little about SELinux, but I ended up discovering the problem with this (on CentOS 6):

```
getsebool httpd_can_sendmail
```

Which told me it's disabled. Fixed with

```
setsebool httpd_can_sendmail 1
```

Comment: setsebool without -P will not survive a reboot. So -P should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You may have SELinux enabled.

http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page

You can check SELinux status by doing:

sestatus

You should see something like:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

You can turn SELinux off temporarily via:

```
echo 0 >/selinux/enforce
```

and back on with

```
echo 1 >/selinux/enforce
```

If you do temp. turn it off, do not install RPMs or make changes. I find this can lead to problems with re-enabling it.

If you want to permanently disable SELinux, then try:

https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux.html

Answer (score 0):

```
getsebool -a | grep mail
allow_postfix_local_write_mail_spool --> off
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```

This command working for me.