# No alive nodes. All the 1 nodes seem to be down

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-9

I am trying to use Elasticsearch 8.1 using laravel. My elasticsearch instance is running at port 9200. `https://localhost:9200` returns me

```
{
  "name" : "node-1",
  "cluster_name" : "my-application",
  "cluster_uuid" : "7wIGGqhBS5OXfV0E4J53GQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.0.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "801d9ccc7c2ee0f2cb121bbe22ab5af77a902372",
    "build_date" : "2022-02-24T13:55:40.601285296Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Inside Laravel, I have following lines of code.

```
$hosts = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:9200',
];
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setSSLVerification(false)
    ->setHosts($hosts)
    ->build();

$params = [
    'index' => 'sample_index',
    'id' => 'sample_id',
    'body' => [
        'name' => 'Sample Product',
        'description' => 'My description...',
        'price' => '3400',
        'stock' => '150',
    ]
];
$response = $client->index($params);
dump($response);
```

The `$response` I get is `No alive nodes. All the 1 nodes seem to be down.` From the dump command above this is request made which is not requesting 9200 (not sure if this is correct or not).

[image: Request made to elastic]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Everything worked fine from python but it always gave this error from the php code. Then google around let me to following article where a person had similar problem

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/1120

And the helper finally pointed him that your httpd need to be allowed to connect to the network and following solution page was referenced:

[CURL permission denied via browser, works on ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622967/curl-permission-denied-via-browser-works-on-ssh/16839153#16839153)

The solution mentioned was to add following line in the php.ini file

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

However, for me it worked when I executed this command with sudo on the command line.

Hope it works for you as well

Comment: Thanks for the information. My issue was due to SSL. So I solved it by following lines of code


`ClientBuilder::create()
            ->setHttpClient(new HttpClient(['verify' => false ]))`

Comment: Hi @nas I've tried your solution but I'm getting error on the new HttpClient saying it can't be instantiated. What class did you import? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @RutherBergonia Sorry for late reply. I have imported `use GuzzleHttp\Client as HttpClient;`


`        return ClientBuilder::create()
            ->setHttpClient(new HttpClient(['verify' => false ]))
            ->setHosts($this->esHost)
            ->setBasicAuthentication($this->esUser, $this->esPass)
            ->build();`

Comment: @nas, I am using Laravel 9 Sail. Do I need to set esUser and esPass ? I don't see username and password in my docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: How did you install elastic search? I am running a docker-image. I noticed that your elastc search is not running on docker.

Comment: Hi @Amit, I installed it thru the zip files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case the problem was an incorrect url because it treats in some weird way and couldn't get transport scheme correctly. For debugging I dump exception with

```php
die($e->getTraceAsString());
```

```
#0 /home/zaek/vendor/elastic/transport/src/Transport.php(296): Elastic\Transport\NodePool\SimpleNodePool->nextNode()
#1 /home/zaek/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Client.php(168): Elastic\Transport\Transport->sendRequest(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))
#2 /home/zaek/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Traits/ClientEndpointsTrait.php(1608): Elastic\Elasticsearch\Client->sendRequest(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))
...
```

As Transport.php is the first in exception stack I go debug this file and found that only way to see occuried error is pass logger to client builder. I'm to lazy to find appropriate class so I just use the good old way to debug I change Transport.php:

```php
} catch (NetworkExceptionInterface $e) {
    die(var_dump($e->getMessage()));
```

And my error was:

```
String(171) "cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: 'https (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://'xxxxxx':'xxxxxx'@'https/%27ingredients_test%27/_search"
```

The reason is it didn't remove quotes when parse .env file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker with ELK + your app, the host should be set NOT localhost, but the container name.

```
 elk:
        container_name: my_app_name_elk
        image: sebp/elk
        ports:
            - "5601:5601"
            - "9200:9200"
            - "5044:5044"
        environment:
            - ELASTICSEARCH_USER=elastic
            - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=password
            - LOGSTASH_USER=elastic
            - LOGSTASH_PASSWORD=password
            - KIBANA_USER=kibana
            - KIBANA_PASSWORD=password
        volumes:
            - elk-data:/var/lib/elasticsearch
```

so as you see in docker-compose I have a service called **elk**, the host of that service will be **elk**

This is in case if you want to access to ELK from your app, which is in docker too
IN CASE IF YOU WANT TO ACCESS OUTSIDE OF DOCKER, just expose ports as I did and access through **localhost:PORT**

Answer (score 0):

I spent days looking for solution

If you using docker-compose and try to connect to elasticsearch from another container make sure they are on same network.

```
 version: '3.8'

 services:
   php-8.2:
     build: docker/php
   ...
   networks:
     - example

   elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticcontainer
    build: docker/elasticsearch
    ...
    networks:
      - example

 networks:
   shovv:
     driver: bridge
```

Then in your client set elasticsearch host as docker container name, like this:

```
$builder = \Elastic\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create();

$builder->setHosts(['elasticcontainer:9200']);

$builder->build();
```